# How can I check two circle collision in my tkinter code?

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection

I have to build a simple program like **bouncing ball simulator** with oop in python and I have built a function movement to move the balls but I have one more requirement is ball collision together, my idea is check the position between the balls but I don't know how, please help me, thanks

And here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title('Bouncing Ball Simulator')
root.resizable(False, False)

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='black')
colors = ['#82ffec', 'red', '#82ffda', '#fa867f', '#ce5fed', '#ff73a4', 'pink', '#ff9912', '#FFB90F', '#BF3EFF',
          '#FFD700', '#00FF00']
gravity = 0.5


def create_circle(x, y, r, canvas_name):
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvas_name.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, outline='#82ffda', fill=random.choice(colors))


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, speedx, speedy, radius):
        top_left_corner = random.randint(20, 100)
        bottom_right_corner = random.randint(5, 70)
        self.radius = radius
        self.speedx = speedx
        self.speedy = speedy
        self.ball = create_circle(top_left_corner, bottom_right_corner, radius, canvas)
        self.movement()

    def movement(self):
        self.speedy += gravity
        canvas.move(self.ball, self.speedx, self.speedy)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.ball)
        if WIDTH <= pos[2] or 0 >= pos[0]:
            self.speedx *= -1
        if 0 >= pos[1] or HEIGHT <= pos[3]:
            self.speedy *= -1
        canvas.after(30, self.movement)


ball_list = [Ball(random.randint(2, 9), random.randint(5, 10), random.randint(10, 20)) for _ in range(50)]

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**I think my idea was right, but I don't know how to calculate distance between two objects (Ball) and how can I compare that with two sum of radius ? Sorry but this is the first time I learn Python and Tkinter lib**

Thanks for reading and more thanks for help :)

Comment: Hate to send you just a link but I came across this nugget a few months ago when I was studying working with objects and canvas in JS. It's a demo and you can derive your collision equations and case selectors from their example. Happy coding! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_building_practice

Comment: Just calculate the distance between the center of the two circles.  If it is less than or equal to the sum of their radii, then the two circles collide.